# Ruby on Rails how to distinguish multiple relationships between same models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have the following models

```
User, Course, Order, Line_item
```

User (seller) `has_many :courses` (as the instructor, uploading them)

On the other hand...

User (buyer): `has_many :orders`

Order: `has many :line_items`

line_item: `belongs_to :course`

So I want a list of all courses purchased by a buyer, can I at this point use `@user.courses` to do so? How can I distinguish between `buyer.courses` and `seller.courses`?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**self-referential association**](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) for this.

```
#cousre.rb
Class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sellar, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sellar_id'
end

#order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'buyer_id'
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `:foreign_key` be in the model that contains the `has_many` definition? In this case the `User` model.

Comment: @MikeSlutsky No! It shouldn't.

Comment: But the link you referenced in your answer shows the `foreign_key` in the `has_many` line. Why is your example different than what you linked to?

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Its a different case!